# How search in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two data `cityname` and `zipcode` .Now i want to find New_york and show the zipcode.
I use this code but nothing shown

```
 $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE cityname LIKE new_york",
               mysql_real_escape_string($prefix));
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

What is the best and fast way to find something in mysql with php ?

Comment: "best" and "fast" are too subjective to be used here. Are you getting any errors? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Dont forget the % at the end - $newyoik = "new_york" ... `LIKE '$newyoik%'`

Comment: Don't forget to quote string literals; or (even better) drop the MySQL extension, switch to MySQLi or PDO, and use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: You still need to check your $query for results

Comment: i don't get any error

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, don't use it. Also: google injection attacks, because you're about to write code that is very vulnerable... also look into MySQL, because you don't seem to be writing correct, working queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE cityname LIKE '%New York%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

The word which will be searched should be in single quotes. Only the word will be a table field / column.

You should use PDO ([More information about PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)) for this, not the old and deprecated mysql_* functions. See comments above from Mark Baker and Elias Van Ootegem.

//**comment #1:**

use `var_dump($query);` for debugging.
Successfully connect to the mysql-server?
Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php to get errors.

//**comment #2:**

what do you get with `echo mysql_errno();` and `echo mysql_error();`

//**comment #3:**

It seems the user need a password or has no access or permissions to the selected database. Check your connection settings on `mysql_connect($server, $username, $password)` or the permissions of the user with phpMyAdmin.

//**comment #4:**

[image]

//**comment #5:**

Which output you get with `SHOW GRANTS FOR my@localhost` on phpmyadmin.

Comment: I tested this but it show nothing i used `echo $query;`

Comment: Small change, I assume your City name does not contain a `_` in the text.

Comment: I got `bool(false)` from `var_dump`

Comment: it said `Access denied for user 'my@localhost' (using password: NO)1045` but i can INSERT to my table i used `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO myTable(cityname, zipcode)
        VALUES ('$cityName', '$code')` and successfully inserted

Comment: I can connect to my database and i also can insert to my database

Comment: and my privileges are okey :|

Comment: it said `Your SQL query has been executed successfully` then `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ...` ,`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`

Comment: Can you show the full code of creating and executing the query (with starting the connection)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE cityname LIKE '%s%%'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($prefix));
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

The sprintf is expecting a `%s` to know where to replace with `$prefix` but you also need to add a `%` to the LIKE to generate `LIKE 'New York%'`, because you are using sprintf it will fail if it see's only one `%` at the end of that format ( as the `%` is its control character) so you have to add 2 `%%` so sprintf will assume this is a `%` that you want in the output and not a incorrect formatting request.
Its sprintf's way of escaping it's control character.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE cityname LIKE '%New York%'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);